Unable to authenticate OpenAPI UI with keycloak and connexion
We are using a basic example from https://github.com/spec-first/connexion/tree/main/examples/oauth2.
Tying to secure the rest api in connextion with keycloak (oauth2 implicit type).
Here is the code
openapi.yaml
openapi: 3.0.0

info:
  title: OAuth Example
  version: "1.0"

servers:
  - url: /openapi

paths:
  /secret:
    get:
      summary: Return secret string
      operationId: app.get_secret
      responses:
        200:
          description: secret response
          content:
            'text/plain':
              schema:
                type: string
      security:
        # enable authentication and require the "uid" scope for this endpoint
        - oauth2: ['ddd']

components:
  securitySchemes:
    oauth2:
      type: oauth2
      x-tokenInfoUrl: http://localhost:8080/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect
      flows:
        implicit:
          authorizationUrl: http://localhost:8080/realms/demo/protocol/openid-connect/auth
          scopes:
            ddd: Unique identifier of the user accessing the service.
            read: ssss

app.py
"""
Basic example of a resource server
"""
from pathlib import Path

import connexion


def get_secret(user) -> str:
    print("aaa")
    return f"You are: {user}"

app = connexion.FlaskApp(__name__, specification_dir="spec")
app.add_api("openapi.yaml")
 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(f"{Path(__file__).stem}:app", port=8081)


This work fine till use authorization but when try to use the token then it gives "Provided token is not valid" error


